# Unexpected error when requesting basic page

Tags: python, python-requests

I am facing a weird problem with requests, I have used this code many times in the past to verify that my header has changed but suddenly I am getting Unicode Error on basic website, not sure what I am doing wrong.
I know the User Agent isn't "correct" but it still should work

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'}
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update( headers)
r = session.get('http://httpbin.org/anything')
print(r.text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/scrapy_tut/fishing/fishing/spiders/insta.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = session.get('http://httpbin.org/anything')
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1280, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1212, in putheader
    values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 30: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: The problem is the ellipsis ('…') character at the end of `'Linu…'`.  Remove it (or use a correct header).

Comment: @snakecharmerb why doesn't `...` work but `.` work, in header

Comment: `...` *would* work. But `…` does not.

Comment: @DanielRoseman why does `. . .` work,why does it give Unicode Error

Comment: Not every character can be encoded as latin-1 - in fact only 256 characters can.  The `horizontal ellipsis` character `…` is not one of the 256, so you get an error.  The full stop character `.` is one of the 256, so no error.  The [256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout)

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks I missed last line in error

Comment: `...` is three [FULL STOPs (U+2E)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm), but `…` is one [HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS (U+2026)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm). Welcome to the confusing world of Unicode, where `a` and `а` are also not the same :P

Comment: Or eventually, you can still do `headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'.encode('utf8')}`.

Comment: But I admit that i dont know how a browser will handlre the results UA:
`"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu\u00e2\u0080\u00a6) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0"`

Comment: @dtrckd bytes headers seems a bit extreme to do I believe

Comment: @Piggydog More than that, its 8 bit extreme :P